# Why is this not valid in C (Arrays)?

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n;
    printf("Enter a value for n\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int A[n];
}
```

Why can't I assign the size of an array explicitly from a user?

Comment: Variable-length arrays are in C99. Maybe you're using an older compiler?

Comment: It would also possibly be an issue if OP is using C11, depending on the compiler, as VLA support was made optional.

Answer (score -1):

There is [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) support in C99 and C11 (optional). With GCC 7.2.1 your example works. I compiled like this:

```
gcc abc.c -o abc

gcc --std=c99 abc.c -o abc
```

Looks like your compiler does not support this feature.

Comment: C/C++ is not a language.  This is a C question so answers relating to C++ constructs are off topic.  Furthermore, C99 supports Variable Length Arrays, and C11 has optional support for VLAs.

Comment: You are correct. C++ does not, C11 does.. will fix the answer shortly...